# In regards to writing, can soda bottles be opened on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-erasing

Specifically, when the writing - such as an expiration date - is printed in dot matrix style across the line between the bottle cap and the bottle cap's ring, what are the issues involved in opening such a bottle?

(Differs from [this question about soda *cans*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/155/799).)

Comment: Do you mean for answerers to address only the issue of the writing? In that case, I think you should make that clear. Other issues do exist, after all.

Comment: Yes, thank you. My specific question is breaking dot matrix style printing apart.

Comment: Great question.  I have always wondered whether the unconnected dots representing normally connected lines is an halachic letter.

Comment: Is erasing a design assur?

Comment: what about saving the recycled bottles for money after shabbat. i have long wondered about that. if one designates (on shabbat) a bottle for recycling, then it gives that particular bottle a monetary value (which can be redeemed after shabbat) is this muttar?
in effect, by doing so, we are engaging and justifying an object for sale (or redemption in this case) after shabbat..... [or would we say, that just as we don't throw away a table cloth, or table or anything else of value on shabbat] so too, by saving the table (which retains its intrinsic value after shabbat) the same analogy would appl

Comment: @mechoel - This is probably worth asking as a new question.

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13513

Answer (score 7):

In Shulchan Aruch (O"Ch siman 340) is mentioned that there is an argument if one is prohibited from opening books with writing on it. 
The reason to be lenient is because one doesn't really do an "action" as the letters are pre-written, you just bring them closer or further from each other. (The Shulchan Aruch HaRav says that the custom is to be lenient).

According to the side that says it is prohibited to open books with writing on Shabbos, it would appear that [bottles should be opened before Shabbos.](http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5760/bo.html)

However, the [Yalkut Yosef](http://rygb.blogspot.com/2008/10/numbers-and-letters-on-bottlecaps.html) permits it because opening a can is a Psik Reisha Dlo Nicha Lei (One doesn't care to have the letters erased) in a Derrabannan case (only erasing for the purpose of writing is from the Torah).

---

However, it is still possible that according to the Shu"a Harav it would still be prohibited to open soda bottles, as a soda cap may be considered one entity with the ring (when it is closed), and opening it may be considered erasing, while in the book it was never on one surface.

---

In the Mishna Brura, it writes that it is forbidden to write and erase any language. Therefore, one could say that a letter made from dots is the same letter with a different "font" (just like braille would be the same letter with a different "font").

http://www.torahlab.org/calendar/article/kosev_writing_on_shabbos/ mentions that writing in braille is prohibited.

Comment: This all applies to letters that are fully formed, with their parts connected in the right places. It's possible none of this applies to letters that were never halachically formed in the first place.

Comment: @tom smith, when you say "opening books with writing on it", are you referring to writing that is formed across the collected edges of the pages when the book is closed (e.g. [this picture](http://www.mywingsbooks.com/coll-terms/edg03_01.jpg) )?

Comment: Tom, I agree if you can open a book with words printed on its side on shabbat, then the cap isn't a problem either. However since this question was specifically about dot-matrix style printing, I'm just pointing out that even those that are stringent and don't open a books or caps with writing on the side may be allowed to open them if it is dot-matrix instead of normally formed letters. It really depends on whether a dot-matrix letter is considered a letter - no matter how many times you open and close the cap, the letter-segments won't get close enough to connect and form a letter.

Comment: @zaq you're right, though the link to torah.org says "Often, there are letters or words written on the sides of plastic bottle caps (e.g., those produced by Pepsi Co.). When the bottle cap is twisted open, these letters may break and become erased. Those bottles should be opened before Shabbos. " Unfortunately, it doesn't bring a source.

Comment: Can you add to the answer to relate to the dot-matrix aspect of the question.

Comment: For completeness, I would just add that a number of the issues raised about the tshuva of R. Ovadia (linked above) are answered in the tshuva of R. Abadi (in my answer). So for those who are interested in an alternate rationale for the heter to open packages with writing, I would recommend looking at both.

Answer (score 4):

R. Abadi (in his tshuvos Ohr Yitzchak) concludes that destroying any type of writing on Shabbos (mocheik) is only forbidden when it is destroying for the purpose of writing. But if the destruction is purely destructive, not for the purpose of further writing, then it is permitted for any need on Shabbos (not just for eating)

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1525&st=&pgnum=215

Comment: @tom smith: I would just edit your comment a little: He claims that others disagree with the Rema too (as you noted), so his answer is not necessarily true just for sefardim. So I'm not sure why you started off your comment saying that, if in the end you note he claims support from Ashkenazic poskim as well. And R. Abadi was the posek of Lakewood, which is not a sefardic community, and I don't think he is thought of as a sefardic posek. Otherwise, of course you are right that others disagree, but that is always true.

Comment: @tom smith: That's fine -- I just got the impression that you were trying to diminish the psak of a recognized posek simply because others disagree. I certainly don't think this was your intent, but your words lead to this impression. But R. Abadi certainly has a right to his own view, and he paskened clearly, and directly on point to the question of interest here. And in many places in his tshuvos, he discusses when an answer applies to sefardim or ashkenazim, but here he draws no distinction. And regarding Lakewood, he was the posek for the yeshiva (after. R. Kotler passed away)

Comment: Can you expand on this further? explain how it applies, whether dot matrix printing is relevant etc.?

Comment: @avi: Any kind of printing or writing or symbols or pictures etc can be torn/erased for any Shabbos purpose (not just eating) according to this tshuva. There is no distinction -- R. Abadi doesn't depend on the type of writing for his heter -- he believes it is allowed in all types of writings or symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line, Sefardim who follow R' Ovadia Yosef can open them.
Others can't.
See: http://doseofhalacha.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/opening-bottles-and-cans-on-shabbos.html

> R’ Yehoshua Neuwirth (Shemiras Shabbos Kehilchasa 9:17) writes that one mustn't open new bottles with metal screw lids, as doing so will make the lid into a kli. One may puncture the lid first, thus rendering it useless and then open the bottle as usual (See Emes L’yaakov OC 314:8). R’ Ribiat (39 Melochos p841) writes that if one has a spare lid, one may open the bottle and discard the lid. R’ Ovadia Yosef (Yechave Daas 2:42) and R’ Eliezer Waldenberg (Tzitz Eliezer 14:45) permit opening such bottles.
>
> R’ Ovadia Yosef (Yalkut Yosef, Shabbos 2:p519) writes that one may open a bottle even if there is writing printed on the lid which will get broken, though R’ Neuwirth and others forbid it.While many are particular not to open plastic lids on Shabbos, R’ Shlomo Zalman Auerbach (quoted in Meor Hashabbos 6:4) allows it, as the cap was already made into a kli in production. One who doesn’t open bottles and cans on Shabbos shouldn't ask someone who usually does to do so for them, though if someone else opened it, they may drink from it (Igros Moshe OC 4:119:5).
>
> Providing the tins are disposed of immediately after use, R’ Shlomo Zalman Auerbach (Minchas Shlomo 2:12, Shemiras Shabbos Kehilchasa 9:n10) and R’ Ovadia Yosef allow one to open them on Shabbos (See Igros Moshe OC 1:122). The Chazon Ish (OC 51:11) writes that by opening a tin, one is creating a kli which is an issur deoraisa.
>
> Even those Poskim who allow opening bottles and tins on Shabbos write that one should ideally open them before Shabbos or puncture the lid (or bottom of the can) before opening them.

Comment: Hi Zvi, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for your recent string of posts! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. Looking forward to seeig you around

Answer (score -1):

The letters were never formed, and as such it shouldn't be erasing to separate them. It's similar to those who hold you could erase Hashem's name from a computer screen because the pixels are just dots close together, and that doesn't count as writing.

edit:
maybe assur d'rabanan

Comment: Do you have a source that dots in the pattern of a letter don't count as a letter? I'm pretty sure that the main argument with respect to computer graphics is not that, but that the images are inherently temporary.

Comment: [1](http://ottmall.com/mj_ht_arch/v13/mj_v13i10.html)&[2](http://ottmall.com/mj_ht_arch/v13/mj_v13i10.html) @ the bottom of each page

Comment: A "kuf" (ק) is properly formed when it is made of two parts, An "A" is not properly formed unless all the parts are connected. There is an argument in the Gemara of whether you are liable for writing part of a letter and stopping. I believe the end result was you're not liable, unless you leave off the top connector of a "chet" (ח) resulting in two "zayins" (זז).