Opening glass bottles on Shabbat
There is a machloket amongst the Poskim whether there is an issur committed when you open plastic bottles which need to be screwed to be removed  on Shabbat. Is there a different din in Halacha in cases where you open a glass bottle with a bottle  opener (not something you’re supposed to screw off), since that doesn’t involve screwing to separate from the bottle?

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/93729/15256 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13513/15256 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9341/15256

The problem is not the screwing, but rather whether you’re creating a utensil with the cap Itself
