# English translation for tzaruch

Tags: hebrew, translation, english

I'm looking for the meaning of "tzaruch" in English.

I have read, in Torah sources, that "tzaruch ochel" means "for the purpose of eating".
Does the word "tzaruch" alone mean "the purpose", or only "purpose", or does this word alone have a different translation in English?

Comment: Hi, i need to understand the meaning of the word, if in Torah i read tzaruch ochel i know it means (for the purpose of eating),, but if only the word "tzaruch" appears alone i don´t know is meaning.   Please help me.

Comment: Sorry, but translation questions are off topic for Mi Yodeya. However, you can come support a Hebrew Language Q&A proposal, where you might be able to ask this question in the future: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75348/hebrew-language?referrer=wuY59ZBbDdHCzDHh3-zT9w2

Comment: @Scimonster, per Tzaruch's comment, this question is about understanding a word seen in Torah sources, and it is therefore on-topic.

Comment: Tzaruch, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! I've edited your question based on your previous comment to make it clearer that it's about understanding a word found in Torah sources. You could make this question even more compelling if you'd [edit] in more precise information about where you've seen this word.

Comment: Do you mean *tzorech* (צורך)?

Comment: Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Hi,  i was reading this /questions/155/is-it-permissible-to-open-soda-cans-on-shabbos   that´s were i read about the word tzaruch.   So the word is "tzaruch" not "tzorech"צורך="necessary".    So the words "for the purpose of eating" is like "לצורך האכילה" , but if i change it to "the purpose of eating" than is translates as "המטרה של אכילה" this make me think that "the purpose" have this translation "המטרה". Don´t know if "המטרה" speak as "tzaruch" or have different meaning and not "the propose".  Sorry for my bad english, this is not my language, i´m Portuguese.  Tanks for your help.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I guess it doesn't warrant closure because this doesn't impugn the motivation behind the question, but it seems to be predicated solely on a typo/speako in [the other question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/155/is-it-permissible-to-open-soda-cans-on-shabbos).