# Opening bottles for me on Shabbos - Jew or Non-Jew?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, gentiles, melacha-creative-work, shaat-hadechak

If I dont open bottles on shabbos because my rav holds that it is a melacha deoraisa, Beshas Hadechak is it better for me to get a jew (whose rav holds its muttar) or non jew to open it for me?

Comment: Assuming the top has no writing on, I was told to punch a hole in the top and then I can remove it.

That's not actually an answer to your question but you should ask your rav is that is an available option to you

The reason my method is permitted (according to what I was told) is that the issur is creating a kli and with a hole in it, the top is not a kli.

Comment: If your Rav holds it's a Torah prohibition, what would the justification be to get another Jew to transgress?

Comment: If your Rav holds it's a Torah prohibition, what would the justification be to get a non-Jew to do it?

Comment: What would "beshas hadechak" mean for a bottle on Shabbat? Medicine for a very sick patient? Nothing else to drink and no neighbors/tap water?

Comment: @mbloch Pregnant lady craving carbonation? Caffeine withdrawal? really really really REALLY wanting a drink of soda?

Comment: @mbloch Only bottle of grape juice in the vicinity?

Answer (score 2):

Extracted from [this M.Y. answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1825/5275):

> Can I ask a person to open it for me?
>
> Even someone who does not open cans on Shabbos may use a can that was
>   opened on Shabbos even if they were opened for him (Iggres Moshe: O"C
>   Chelek Daled Siman Kuf Yud Tes Ois Heh) and does not require the
>   person who opened it to drink from it. Non the less he may not ask
>   someone to open it for him(Kuntres Yad Dodi, Harav Dovid Feinstein,pg.
>   31).

Your question of "better" is irrelevant, here. As stated above, you can't sepcifically ask a Jew to open the bottle. And there is a general rule that something that is prohibited for you, cannot be requested from a non-Jew either.

As stated in the comments, I can't imagine any emergency that requires opening a bottle of soda. If you needed the soda for urgent health reasons such as a doctor said you must take a pill daily (else you may become dangerously sick) and there was no water around to wash dow nyour pill, and the bottle of seltzer is the only thing - well then this sounds likes safek pikuach nefesh, and YOU can open the bottle yourself.

Aside this, according to the above, the best you can do is benefit from a Jew who opened the bottle of soda without your asking him.

Comment: What about HaKal HaKal?

Comment: @DoubleAA What are you saying?

Comment: http://ph.yhb.org.il/plus/01-27-05-02/ (but if you don't know that then I don't know how you are comfortable posting your reasoning as remotely conclusive)

Comment: @DoubleAA I read it, but I still don't get what he's saying. Can you summarize the concept?